# Repeat parent group if child group goes to another page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a report that allows Finance to print off multiple invoices at the same time.  The problem I'm running into is that they want the Bill To information repeated on each page of the invoice.

I have two groups set up on the report.  Group A is grouped on Document Number.  Group B is grouped on Line Item.  It works perfectly fine when I running multiple invoices (multple document numbers), but I can't figure out how to get the information from Group A to repeat on the second (or third, etc.) page of the Invoice.

How can I get the Parent Group (Group A) to repeat on subsequent pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, make sure you've enabled **Advanced Mode** in the Grouping section:

[image]

For each Group Header row, set the **RepeatOnNewPage** property to `True`.

[image]

[image]

This should do the trick - you might need to play around with it a bit more; in my experience it can be quite tricky to get everything correct.

For more detail see [Repeat Header / Keep Header Visible in Tables in RS 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Under Design Pane - > Row Groups - > click on (static) - > Press F4  - > Properties window will pop up.

In the Properties window - >Set KeepWithGroup =  After and RepeatOnNewPage = True.

If you want the header to be frozen while scrolling down the report, set FixedData = True.