# SSRS How to repeat the table header on each page in print preview

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report, for some reason the header is not repeating on all of the pages in the print preview mode. Below is the image of the table:[image]

I have as well checked the Repeat Header rows on each page option as below:

[image]

I would like the headers to repeat on every page.

Comment: Check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701486/repeat-parent-group-if-child-group-goes-to-another-page/

Comment: Have a look at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx) hopefully it should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tablix: Repeat header rows on each page not working - Report Builder 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0)

Comment: The answer marked as correct is indeed correct. However for people unfamiliar with Reporting Services, it's not as clear as the one on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To repeat rows with column headings for a table with row groups

- In Design view, select the table. The Grouping pane displays the row groups.
- On right side of the Grouping pane, click the down arrow, and then click Advanced. The Grouping pane displays static and dynamic tablix members for each group. You can only set properties on a static tablix member.
- In the Row Groups pane, click the static tablix member for the row that you want to repeat. When you select a static tablix member, the corresponding cell on the design surface is selected, if there is one. The Properties pane displays the properties for the selected tablix member.

  - Set the `KeepWithGroup` property in the following way:

    - For a static row that is above a group, click After.
    - For a static row that is below a group, click Before.
  - Set the `RepeatOnNewPage` property to `True`.

Comment: Saved my sanity!

Comment: To add to the above, if you have multiple static rows at the top of your report (e.g. to say which parameters were set) you need to set RepeatOnNewPage to True for **all of them** even though only the one with KeepWithGroup=After will repeat. Otherwise you get error *"The TablixMember must have the same value set for the RepeatOnNewPage property as those following or preceding the dynamic TablixMember"*. No idea why you have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here i got a solution :

```
1. In the Tablix properties check the boxes for: Repeat header rows on each page and Keep header visible while scrolling.
make sure that the column headrs check boxes are NOT checked.
2. In the Group pane on the left (Row Groups) the first line is static. 
3. set its: "ReapetOnNewPage" property to TRUE
set its: "FixedData" property to TRUE
set its: "KeepWithGroup" property to AFTER
```

Comment: Here's what I have been doing.  It overlaps with above, but there are more steps:  1.Select the Tablix
2. Delete the existing row of headings
3. Select a row group cell
4. Insert new row outside group – above
5. Go to column groups in the lower right and click the down arrow to go into advanced mode
6. Select the first static item in row groups (on the left).  You should see the first new column heading highlighted in the Tablix.  In properties, set RepeatOnNewPage to true.  Repeat for other static items mapped to the new column headings.
7. Enter the column headings on the new row