# SSRS - Column headers repeat on new pages, but not over summary rows

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, columnheader

I've got column headers repeating on each page of my SSRS report, (PDF) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775451/ssrs-how-to-repeat-the-table-header-on-each-page-in-print-preview). (among many other places) The problem I'm having now is that if the new page happens to have only summary rows, (totals, averages, etc) then the column headers do not appear. Here's what a normal page looks like:

[image]

And here's how it looks when the page only has "total" rows on it:

[image]

Here's the xml from the rdl file that accompanies each column header currently, in order to get the repeating effect:

```
<TablixMember>
    <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
    <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
</TablixMember>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You could try adding an extra group layer (group on a literal like '1'). Put the column headers in the table header rows and put the total columns in the dummy group footer. Writing this in a comment, not an answer, because I haven't tried this. But it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks - I'll play around with it and see what happens.

Comment: No luck. It looks like the way it's built should effectively accomplish that, anyway, as the group the column headers are associated with will always be there. I should mention that I'm not getting too extreme with my attempted changes, b/c the report goes into production very soon, and this is a minor issue, so we're reluctant to make a change that could have negative side effects.