# Repeat header in SSRS with Row Group in body

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have designed simple SSRS report, the thing is like I have data which is splitted into master details using sub-reports, and I have kept these into a Row Group control in body part of main report.

Here the header which I placed in main report is getting repeated only as per row  and it is not visible if a details of specific records is gets spilled over next page.

How can I show the header on each and every page irrespective of the row (record)?

Please find below screen shot for details.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see link to answer below:

You'll want to select the the Advanced Mode where you can select row detail. Here, you should be able to select the Static row columns. On the right in the Properties, you'll want to set "RepeatOnNewPage" to **True**

[SSRS How to repeat the table header on each page in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775451/ssrs-how-to-repeat-the-table-header-on-each-page-in-print-preview)

Comment: I already tried with this solution and facing with an below error:

The tablix 'Tablix8' has an invalid TablixMember. All TablixMember elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the RepeatOnNewPage property set to false.

This is only because I have used Group Box for the entire body area to show relative records on respective pages.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the layout and the Row detail information with an indicator of what you are trying to achieve? It would be very helpful