# SSRS stops repeating column header every page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tablix report with subreport. I have checked my settings based on this [ssrs-how-to-repeat-the-table-header-on-each-page-in-print-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775451/ssrs-how-to-repeat-the-table-header-on-each-page-in-print-preview) and this [Column headers not displaying on each page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/54e605d4-07b4-40d9-925d-563f81a0828b/column-headers-not-displaying-on-each-page?forum=sqlreportingservices).
However, the header columns are still displayed on the first 2,3 pages of the report and then they stop showing. The report is not too long. It ranges from 1 to roughly 15 pages.

I use VS 2013.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Which headings are not displaying? The tablix or the subreport?

Comment: At this time, I'm more concerned with the tablix heading not showing. The subreport I have not time to find a sample that has rows spilled over to the  next page yet.