# Display row and column Headers on multiple pages in sql reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**I have a SQL report which has 7-8 headers like:-**

```
S.No. Name Address Contact ......
```

On a single page only 10 records are displayed, now when I navigate to second page
all the headers disappear causing users to come back again to first page to see which record belongs to which header. I did all the things given in the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx but when I deploy my sql report it gives me an error.

```
The definition of the report '/IncomeReport' is invalid.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701486/repeat-parent-group-if-child-group-goes-to-another-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixing header, you need to go to advanced mode, select static member and set fix data true. Please see Robert's blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: I am marking this as an answer but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701486/repeat-parent-group-if-child-group-goes-to-another-page/ was also helpful.