# SSRS - Print tablix row header on each new page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix which it has assigned a dataset. Tablix iterates over the dataset returned. I have placed a rectangle object with content within tablix row header and check the option to print row headers on each new page in tablix properties. First row of the tablix corresponds to the row header and second row contains is a subreport that contains a chart that is generated based on the data returned by the dataset on each iteration (at each iteration a new chart is created with the appropiate data).

My problem is when a new page starts, the row header is not printed at the beginning of the new page. The first time, row header is printed but not in the next new pages.

I will highly appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Please check this solution with all screenshots http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701486/repeat-parent-group-if-child-group-goes-to-another-page/

Comment: @ravi I have done the same as your link explains but it is not working for me. I have to say that my second row is a subreport thati contains a chart. I have edited the original post.

Comment: @ravi If I insert a new row above the table header and delete the old header row it "works", I mean, it partially works, when I export to PDF it is working ok, well formatted into PDF, but from SSDT preview tab it is not showing correctly. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Set the RepeatOnNewPage property instead:

- Go to View and enable the Properties pane.
- Click on the Tablix and and toggle Advanced Mode. (Using the arrow to the right of the Column Groups label.)
- Click through the row groups named "Static" until you find the one corresponding to the row you want to appear on each page.
- In the Properties pane under Other group, set the RepeatOnNewPage property to "true".

Comment: i forgot to say that my chart in this case is a subreport. I have done but it is not working. In tablix properties I have selected "repeat header rows on each page" then in advance mode, I select static, my row header is selected and in the tablix member properties I set below properties: FixedData=true, Hidden=false,HideIfNoRows=true,KeepTogether=true,KeepwithGroup=After,RepeatOnNewPage=true.

Also In advance mode, in row group section I select Details, and for details I set KeepTogether=false, fixedData=false.

Comment: As I said to @ravi If I insert a new row above the table header and delete the old header row it "works", I mean, it partially works, when I export to PDF it is working ok, well formatted into PDF, but from SSDT preview tab it is not showing correctly. Why?

Comment: I would need to take a look, but I would be less than surprised if the rending of subreports between environments was part of the issue.  If you temporarily delete the chart subreport, does the preview match the PDF behavior?